# Merge all Language learning Stack Exchange sites together?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange

I'm confused by why there are so many separate sites for specific languages on here. Wouldn't it be better to just have one "Languages" Stack Exchange where you can indicate which language you're asking about with the tags? As it is, if I want to ask about ancient Greek dialects I have to post on the "Latin" Stack Exchange, and if I have a question about Ghandaran or Pali I have to go to the "Buddhism" one, and if I have a question about Klingon grammar I have to post on the Sci-fi and fantasy site (where it will most likely be closed as off-topic). As far as I know there's nowhere for me to ask about Toki or Ithkuil (although perhaps the Esperanto site might accept a question about these languages). Just wondering about the rationale for having so many separate sites. Is it possible to merge them all into one "Languages" site where any and every language would be on-topic?

Comment: I agree. I have no where to ask Mongolian questions.

Comment: Why do you assume that, say, Mongolian speakers will sprout from the ground and answer questions about Mongolian, rather than the IMO more realistic expectation that the question would simply disappear because of not being relevant to the dozen European language speakers in such a mega site? I think every question on the front page being about every language would look rather unappealing and unattractive.

Answer (score 15):

> I'm confused by why there are so many separate sites for specific languages on here.

Because each one is its own thriving community, with (within limits) their own authority how to control the site. That includes things like allowing posts in the language itself (for better immersion); it would be a mess if we have a home page with questions in five or more different languages. Also, consider reviews and flags: it could be hard for French users to review German posts, or for the German moderators to handle a flag in French or about a post in French. Yet another example: some sites use the non-English language for tags; so [gramática](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gram%c3%a1tica) is the same as [грамматика](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0). Sites would lose that freedom when they would be merged.

Incidentally, there *is* a Stack Exchange dedicated to [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) but it only accepts questions about the learning process, not general questions about grammar or meaning. Also, there is a site for [Constructed Languages](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/) which accepts both Toki and Ithkuil questions.

You might also be interested in [Would a general Languages.SE supersite (synchronized with the current language sites) be feasible?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29986/151554) on Area 51 Discussions.